# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tridion Stack Exchange](http://tridion.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Publishing Process, Some pages are not actually copied to file system](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3953/publishing-process-some-pages-are-not-actually-copied-to-file-system)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Error trying to save the schema: "The complexType 'uuid:7a55541b-9084-4b21-9351-06b3d1c0b4f2:Content' has already been declared."](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/error-trying-to-save-the-schema-the-complextype-uuid7a55541b-9084-4b21-9351)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Process Download Links Extension Bug](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/process-download-links-extension-bug)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Custom Counter not Template Repeat Index](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/custom-counter-not-template-repeat-index)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [cd_storage config with Oracle](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/cd-storage-config-with-oracle)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to reference to external assembly in TBB tridion assembly?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/how-to-reference-to-external-assembly-in-tbb-tridion-assembly)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Migrating Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2013 SP1 with out disturbing existing environment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3861/migrating-tridion-2011-to-tridion-2013-sp1-with-out-disturbing-existing-environm)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Unable to select image or table in an RTF field using a mouse in Chrome](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/unable-to-select-image-or-table-in-an-rtf-field-using-a-mouse-in-chrome)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [HTTP 404: File not found, reverting to mimetype](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3974/http-404-file-not-found-reverting-to-mimetype)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---